# SQL join statement returned unexpected records

Tags: sql

I ran the script below.  There is no record in UserDetails.User# that mataches AccountDetails.User#.  But the results show Every user# in UserDetails 3 times with each AccountDetails.account# specified in the script.
When there is no match in the SQL join statement, should it not return anything?

little background on the DataType and sample values:

```
UserDetails.user# 
datatype = varchar(520)
values in (1,0)

AccountDetails.user#
datatype = varchar(11)
values in (22054414,28581057,26178648)
```

The script I ran:

```
SELECT a.account#  , a.userNum , u.userNum, u.Name
FROM AccountDetails a
JOIN UserDetails u ON a.userNum = u.userNum
WHERE a.account# IN (87173000,11900008,79000082)
```

Sample results:

```
account#,    a.userNum, u.userNum ,    u.Name
87173000,     22054414,     1,       Joe Blow
87173000,     28581057,     1,       John Smith
11900008,     22054414,     1,       Joe Blow
11900008,     28581057,     1,       John Smith
79000082,     22054414,     1,       Joe Blow
79000082,     28581057,     1,       John Smith
```

Comment: I usually use inner join instead of just join for readability; but I don't see how that would help here.  (unless the engine is seeing it as a CROSS join (which it shouldn't)) add inner just to try?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.account , a.user , u.Name
FROM AccountDetails a 
JOIN UserDetails u ON (a.user = u.user) 
WHERE a.account IN (87173000,11900008,79000082)
GROUP BY a.user
```

Comment: i don't think this works...  you have items in your select list that aren't aggregates and aren't in the group by.

Comment: MySQL allows some odd things in GROUP BY lists; standard SQL and most other DBMS do not.